# With mypy, how do I type annotate a decorator that decorates a function that accepts a subclass of something?

Tags: python, types, static-analysis, mypy

For full context, I was hoping to make some decorators that did better static analysis for tests. In an ideal world it would work something like this:

```py
class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @login_decorate
    def test_login(self):
        reveal_type(self.user)  # type: User

    @anonymous_decorate
    def test_anonymous(self):
        reveal_type(self.user)  # type: None
```

And just to get started, I was trying to create a decorator that looked something like this:

```py
def login_decorate(func: Callable[[unittest.TestCase], None]):
    def decorated_function(self: unittest.TestCase):
        self.user = User()
        return func(self)
    return decorated_function
```

But then when I ran mypy I got this error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "login_decorate" has incompatible type "Callable[[SomeTest], None]";
expected "Callable[[TestCase], None]"
```

After thinking on it a bit, I agree that this is the correct behavior for mypy due to contravariance, but that doesn't help me solve my problem.

Is there any way to get the decorator to work elegantly without explicitly hacking the type with `Any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that mypy check fails because `Callable` is contravariant.
It can be fixed by using type variables.

```py
import unittest
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=unittest.TestCase)


def login_decorate(func: Callable[[T], None]):
    def decorated_function(self: T):
        ...
        return func(self)
    return decorated_function


class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @login_decorate
    def test_login(self):
        ...
```