# How to alias generic types for decorators

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider the [example of a typed decorator bound to certain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406717/620382).

```
import unittest
from typing import *

T = TypeVar("T", bound=unittest.TestCase)

def decorate(func: Callable[[T], None]) -> Callable[[T], None]:
    def decorated_function(self: T) -> None:
        return func(self)
    return decorated_function
```

Now I even have [a generator that creates these decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#tagging-tests) and want to shorthand these decorators. What type do I to the variables variables storing the decorator (simplified example omitting the generator).

```
my_decorate: Callable[[Callable[[T], None]], Callable[[T], None]] = decorate
```

This works, but is clunky. So the question is:

***How can I alias this type to avoid having to write the the full signature?***

---

Things that don't work:

```
TD = Callable[[Callable[[T], None]], Callable[[T], None]]
my_decorate: TD[T] = decorator_variable
```

Gives the error

```
error: Type variable "mypytest.T" is unbound
note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
```

In contrast, I can use `TD[T]` as argument type for a function.

Just using `my_decorate: TD = ...` yields a `--strict` error

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "TD"
```

And it no longer detects wrong applications of `my_decorate`.

Comment: does `my_decorate: TD = decorator_variable` not work (without setting `T` to `Any`)?

Comment: Omitting `[T]` yields a `--strict` error and no longer performs the expected type-check on `self`. I added details to the question.

Comment: *They (type variables) serve as the parameters for generic types as well as for generic function definitions.* But you try to use type variable outside the context.

Comment: @alex_noname you are right. How can I use a sensible type alias without?

Comment: You may want to review Python documentation on typing decorators: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#functions-and-decorators

Also, this is Python. Please don't get carried away with the whole typing thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in many cases, when `Callable` is too limited use a `Protocol` instead:

```py
class TD(Protocol):
    """Type of any callable `(T -> None) -> (T -> None)` for all `T`"""
    def __call__(self, __original: Callable[[T], None]) -> Callable[[T], None]:
        ...
```

`TD` is *not* a generic type and thus does not need "filling in" a type variable. It can be used directly as an annotation:

```py
my_decorate: TD = decorate
```

Notably, `TD.__call__` is still a generic callable even though `TD` is not generic. Its `T` is filled by the context of each call as desired.

Comment: I didn't know about `Protocol`. I learned something new today. Thank you for this answer @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: Brilliant combination... I knew of `Protocol`, but using it with `__call__` to apply it only on functions does the trick! Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It is shorter than the full signature:

```
import unittest
from typing import *

T = TypeVar("T", bound=unittest.TestCase)


def decorate(func: Callable[[T], None]) -> Callable[[T], None]:
    def decorated_function(self: T) -> None:
        return func(self)

    return decorated_function


decorator_variable: Callable[[Callable[[T], None]], Callable[[T], None]] = decorate

U = Callable[[T], None]
my_decorate: Callable[[U[T]], U[T]] = decorator_variable
```